# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider <- ngTableParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to use **ng-table** and tried adding it on many places but its giving error for all cases.

When I am adding `ngTable` in app.js, its giving:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ngTableParamsProvider <- ngTableParams

When I am adding `ngTable` in controller, its giving undefined is not a function for controller.

How should I resolve it?

Comment: Can you create a plunker? My guess though is that you are not injecting  ngTable into your module like this http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/example/1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need

1. Add reference to `<script src="....ng-table.js"></script>` (more likely in in your index.html file)
2. Inject ngTable to your angular module ie:

   `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngTable']);`
3. in controller

   `myApp.controller('someCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams) {....});`

Comment: I did the same but then it was giving undefined is not a function for controller.

Comment: can you post your controller code or create plnkr ?

Comment: did this also but still the same error undefined is not a function for controller. I am creating plnkr. Will post soon

Comment: Hi 99% step 2. please double check I've just get error like you when I removed ngTable from array

Comment: Thanks @sylwester . Actually I was using multiple controllers and in all, I was using
    angular.module('myApp',['ngTable']).controller('ctrl',...)
So later on defining angular app in parent like you said in 2nd step worked to resolve problem.

Answer (score 23):

Another cause of this error is renaming of `ngTableParams` into `NgTableParams` in [version 1.0.0](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). So, if you are using version 1.0.0, the code should look like this:

```
customModule.factory("customTable", function (NgTableParams) {

    function setupNgTable() {
        var parameters = {
            count: 10
        };

        var settings = {
            getData: function (params) {

            }
        };

        return new NgTableParams(parameters, settings);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

It looks like `ngTableParams` has been now changed to `NgTableParams`, starting with "N" instead of 'n'.

So, now the code will look something like this...

First, Add `ng-table.js` or `ng-table.min.js` link in your HTML code.

Then in your app.js or in the script part do like this...

```
var app = angular.module('XXX', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('XXXXX', function($scope, NgTableParams){

//-Inside wherever your using ngTableParams change it to NgTableParams

................

});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: To format code indent with 4 spaces to make your answer more readable. ;)

Comment: Thanks @sidneydobber

Answer (score 4):

In order to use ngTable module you need to follow the steps in http://ng-table.com

Mind that `NgTableParams` injection is with **capital N**